# Can't view realm file in Realm Studio (Version 13.0.0) on macOS Ventura 13.0

Tags: realm, mongodb-realm, realm-studio

[image]

I tried to open *realm demo file* in Realm Studio but all that I see is the above image. I've tried  several times but still same results.

Comment: Realm Studio is a third party application written by MongoDB Realm. If you found a bug, best bet is to report it to them directly as there's nothing we can do about it here on SO. Check out the [Github Releases](https://github.com/realm/realm-studio/releases) and there's an issues tab where you can file a bug report. When you tried to open a file, did it present a popup if you wanted to upgrade in place, backup and upgrade or cancel?

Comment: Thank you @Jay really appreciate your comment, I will check it out.